# Can I see the custom_friendly_name used in each Twilio Verify verification SMS anywhere?

Tags: twilio, twilio-verify

My company uses Twilio Verify with the custom_friendly_name feature to display our customer's company name in the SMS. We'd like to see the custom friendly name that was sent with each verification to  aggregate usage by customer. Is this possible?

I looked through the Verify logs in the Twilio Console but custom_friendly_name is not part of the information for each verification.

Answer (score 0):

From the console, you have a Service ID / friendly name filter.

You can use it to get only messages sent using a certain friendly name.

[image]